# Given a header file, Is there a way I can find out which library it belongs to?

Tags: c

The source codes downloaded from internet has a lot of non standard, uncommon header files
from a different depended modules, say.

```
#include<calendar.h>
```

or

```
#include <vconf.h>
```

Given any header file, is there a way to find out from which files these headers are fetched from?

Comment: It's just a text, so - no, there is no guaranteed way. Googling file name or its contents or looking into comments at the beginning of file may help. Maybe your project even have README file that contains information about what libraries it uses.

Comment: Do you have a set of candidate libraries available on your system, or you want to do this using only the source code in order to find the libraries?

Comment: Every header files should either be pulled from a .h file or .so, .o files. If that is the case, I want to know how compiler locates such a file. If compiler can, Why can't we?

Comment: What that supposed to mean? Header is a text file, period. You give compiler search paths and it it looks for header file within these paths (plus some predefined paths, like `/usr/include`), nowhere else.

Comment: @keltar How do we specify compiler search path?

Comment: @user3400391 depends on compiler. There are `-I/file/path` options for `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: @keltar So in case of the source codes downloaded, these information is held by Makefiles?

Comment: @user3400391 more or less so. Or just look at compilation line when make outputs it.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053681/is-it-possible-to-identify-the-library-that-correspond-to-certain-header-files)

Answer (score 1):

look at the documentation of the lib to that the header belongs may the best way.

you also may look into the header and note down some function names and search through the lib which does define the symbol that belongs to that function

edit:
 
ah i thought you have a bunch of libs and headers and you do not know which you have to link to get functionality that is declared in a specific header

In your case looking at documentation from downloaded source code may be the only way (mostly this information is in the INSTALL or README - file)

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general.

The string inside of #include is just a filename, and those can easily be reused by different projects, especially generic names like "calendar.h".

You could try googling the header names, or try to compile and google the function names that are used in the downloaded code, but defined in the missing header file.  You could try asking the author of the code, or looking for more information from where you downloaded the code.